Method does not override any method from its superclass" Flutter with url_launcher and youtube_player_flutter
I’m working on a Flutter project, and I’m encountering a Swift Compiler Error when trying to run my app on the iOS simulator. Here’s the error message I’m getting:
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Method does not override any method from its superclass
/Users/User/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_inappwebview-5.8.0/ios/Classes/InAppWebView/InAppWebView.swift:1225:25


I am able to run other projects so the problem is not with configurations.
My pubspec.yaml Includes:
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^6.2.5
  youtube_player_flutter: ^8.1.2
  url_launcher_ios: ^6.2.4

What I've Tried:

Updating youtube_player_flutter and url_launcher_ios to their latest versions.
Cleaning and rebuilding the project using:

flutter pub upgrade --major-versions


Checking if flutter_inappwebview is directly listed in my pubspec.yaml. It’s not there, but it seems to be included as a transitive dependency.

my Xcode version is
Version 16.1 (16B40)
in my pub get outdated
Package Name                               Current     Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest   

direct dependencies:                      
getwidget                                  *2.1.1      *2.1.1      4.0.0       4.0.0    
google_mobile_ads                          *2.4.0      *2.4.0      5.2.0       5.2.0    
http                                       *0.13.6     *0.13.6     1.2.2       1.2.2    
intl                                       *0.18.1     *0.18.1     *0.19.0     0.20.0   
persistent_bottom_nav_bar                  *5.0.2      *5.0.2      6.2.1       6.2.1    
table_calendar                             *3.0.9      *3.0.9      3.1.2       3.1.2    
youtube_player_flutter                     *8.1.2      *8.1.2      9.1.1       9.1.1    

dev_dependencies:                         
flutter_launcher_icons                     *0.11.0     *0.11.0     0.14.1      0.14.1   

transitive dependencies:                  
async                                      *2.11.0     *2.11.0     *2.11.0     2.12.0   
characters                                 *1.3.0      *1.3.0      *1.3.0      1.3.1    
clock                                      *1.1.1      *1.1.1      *1.1.1      1.1.2    
collection                                 *1.18.0     *1.18.0     *1.18.0     1.19.1   
dots_indicator                             *2.1.2      *2.1.2      *2.1.2      3.0.0    
flutter_inappwebview                       *5.8.0      *5.8.0      6.1.5       6.1.5    
flutter_inappwebview_android               -           -           1.1.3       1.1.3    
flutter_inappwebview_internal_annotations  -           -           1.1.1       1.1.1    
flutter_inappwebview_ios                   -           -           1.1.2       1.1.2    
flutter_inappwebview_macos                 -           -           1.1.2       1.1.2    
flutter_inappwebview_platform_interface    -           -           1.3.0+1     1.3.0+1  
flutter_inappwebview_web                   -           -           1.1.2       1.1.2    
flutter_inappwebview_windows               -           -           0.6.0       0.6.0    
http_parser                                *4.0.2      *4.0.2      *4.0.2      4.1.1    
material_color_utilities                   *0.11.1     *0.11.1     *0.11.1     0.12.0   
meta                                       *1.15.0     *1.15.0     *1.15.0     1.16.0   
path                                       *1.9.0      *1.9.0      *1.9.0      1.9.1    
string_scanner                             *1.2.0      *1.2.0      *1.2.0      1.4.0    
visibility_detector                        *0.3.3      *0.3.3      -           0.4.0+2  
webview_flutter                            -           -           *4.9.0      4.10.0   
webview_flutter_android                    -           -           *3.16.9     4.1.0    
webview_flutter_platform_interface         -           -           2.10.0      2.10.0   
webview_flutter_wkwebview                  -           -           3.16.3      3.16.3   

My question:
Why is this error showing and how to fix it. This error only started occurring after updating Xcode.

The youtube_player_flutter package uses an older version of the flutter_inappwebview plugin, causing this issue. It's a known problem; see Issue #2381 in flutter_inappwebiew.
To resolve this issue, you can update the youtube_player_flutter to the latest version or override the dependency of the flutter_inappwebview.

It's works for me thanks.
